# Pages: Change Body Style for Entire document

Tags: pages, formatting

I'm using Pages 5.5.3 on OS X 10.10.4. I can't figure out how to change the size of the Body style for the entire document. If I try to increase the size of the Body text it only changes the size of the text where my cursor was last - the rest of the document is unaffected.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Did you try selecting all text using "⌘ A"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on the font size selector, an <kbd>Update</kbd> button appears beside the style you have selected:

[image: Pages - update style throughout the document]

Click on it and the style is updated to the new parameters. Existing and new text with this paragraph style will adopt them.