# Apple Pages - how to change style globally?

Tags: pages

Using Pages 13.0 on macOS Monterey.

I have a Pages document where I have paragraph titles formatted as style "Heading", and the remaing part as style "Body".

I wanted to insert numbering into the Heading. I proceeded as follows:

- Put the cursor on the first paragraph with format "Heading".
- Change in the "Format pane" (where "Heading" is selected) "Bullets & Lists" to "Numbered"
- Click the checkmark for "Tiered Numbers"
- Select the radio button for "Continue from previous"

This made my first heading indeed be prefixed by the number 1, but the second heading further down still does not have a number. Checking the Format pane, I placed the cursor into that second "Heading" paragraph and found that my changes have not been applied. I did the same to that paragraph and now got the number 2 in front of the heading.

Of course I don't want to do the same process over and over again. The style should be changed uniformly to my whole document. I found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194689/pages-change-body-style-for-entire-document) discussion which suggests that an "Update" button is supposed to appear next to a style name, when I change the style, and that this button would make the changes permanent. However, I don't see such a button.

[image: Here is how my modified update pane looks like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pages list bullets are not reflected in paragraph styles. In stead, lists are reflected in "List styles."

You can create a list format and then use the dropdown to redefine or define a new list style based on your preferences.

Then, every time you want it, you can use the same dropdown to select that list style for the new entry.

[image: Bullets & Lists - List Styles]

Like with Paragraph styles (see below), an asterisk indicates a formatting difference and an Update button may present to update a definition quickly.

---

Unfortunately, it does not appear that "Continue from previous" sticks in the styles. You can define everything else, but that appears to reset to starting from 1 in every new list.

---

A note on paragraph styles, since you also touched on those:

In Pages, every block of text has a "Paragraph Style" associated with it. For example, body text in a default document is styled as "Body" as you type it out.

If the text your cursor is on has formatting changes applied that are not reflected in its underlying style, an asterisk (*) will appear next to the name of the style. You may also see an Update button depending on how much of the text matches the new, different style (a single word in a paragraph being bold will not trigger the Update button).

If the Update button does not appear, you can still open the style dropdown, and click the `>` arrow menu button next to the style you want to update, and click "Redefine from Select."

[Pages Manual: Paragraph Styles](https://support.apple.com/guide/pages/intro-to-paragraph-styles-tanaa39b0aa3/13.0/mac/13.3.1)

Comment: But isn't it then only for lists inside my body text? I want my chapter titles be numbered.

Comment: You're still using the Bullets & Lists option to format your chapter titles, they work the same in headers as in the body.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it means that instead of redefining the current style named _Heading_ to include numbering, I need to create a completely new style and use **this** for my chapter titles?

Comment: @user1934428 No, I don't believe so - I believe that the paragraph styles and the list styles cannot interact. You can format bold/italic/font/etc. with the more prominent paragraph styles, but list settings will not save to that. List settings only save to the List styles popup shown in the screenshot.

Comment: So it means that if I have in a document severa paragraphs where I assigned the style "Heading" to them, there is no way that I can change this style once and apply the changes to all "Heading" paragraphs at once? Because right now I have to manually apply the changes to each "Heading"-paragraph individually.

Comment: For list based formatting, yes it would appear so. You could change them all to be underlined and they should stay in sync (if the update button doesn't appear you can still redefine "Heading" to be any selected text) but the list numbering doesn't appear to be part of that

Comment: Thanks a lot explaining. This seems to be a rather bizarre design decision by Apple .....